# How to set xticks and font properties of pyplot subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to plot the usage frequencies of emoji in different types of tweets ('normal' tweets, retweets, and replies).
To this aim, I'm using the TwitterColorEmoji-SVGinOT ([link](https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font)) font to render the Unicode of emoji that I put as xticks labels with **plt.xticks()**.
However, it correctly sets the xticks of the last subplot only (see the Figure below).

How can I do the same for all the subplots?

This is the code that I'm using to produce the plots.

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
from matplotlib import ft2font
from matplotlib.font_manager import ttfFontProperty

def print_emoji_freq(emoji_freqs, ax, fontprop):

    emojis = list(zip(*emoji_freqs))[0]
    scores = list(zip(*emoji_freqs))[1]
    x_pos = np.arange(len(emojis))

    ax.bar(x_pos, scores, align='center')
    plt.xticks(x_pos, emojis, fontproperties=fontprop)

    ax.set_xticks(x_pos)
    ax.set_ylabel('Popularity Score')

fpath = '/home/mattia/.local/share/fonts/TwitterColorEmoji-SVGinOT.ttf'
fprop = fm.FontProperties(fname=fpath)

font = ft2font.FT2Font(fpath)
fprop = fm.FontProperties(fname=fpath)

ttfFontProp = ttfFontProperty(font)

fontprop = fm.FontProperties(family='sans-serif',
                            fname=ttfFontProp.fname,
                            size=25,
                            stretch=ttfFontProp.stretch,
                            style=ttfFontProp.style,
                            variant=ttfFontProp.variant,
                            weight=ttfFontProp.weight)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(18,4))

print_emoji_freq(st_emojis, ax[0], fontprop)
print_emoji_freq(rt_emojis, ax[1], fontprop)
print_emoji_freq(rp_emojis, ax[2], fontprop)

plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Comment: did you try replace plt.xticks with ax.set_xticks?

Comment: `plt.xticks` applies to the currently active axes, which is the last one being created. Instead use the actual axes, `ax.set_xticks` and `ax.set_xticklabels`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ImportanceOfBeingErnest suggests, you cannot use `plt.xticks()` as they apply to the current axes (`plt.gca()`). You need to use the `ax` object for this:

```
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_function(ax):
    fm = FontProperties(weight='bold')
    ax.set_xticks([1, 3, 5])
    ax.set_xticklabels(['one', 'three', 'five'], fontproperties=fm)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3)

plot_function(ax[0])
plot_function(ax[1])
plot_function(ax[2])
```

[image]